# Azure Application Gateway backend settings is somehow being overwritten. I changed it from 30 to 900 before and now it is back to 30

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway, azure-application-settings

In order to make my application specific tasks avoid timeout errors, inside AKS cluster, I have changed the backend settings of my azure application gateway "Request time-out (seconds)" from 30 to 900. However, it reverts back to be 30 when I check it next time. What can we do to make this timeout setting a permanent change.

[image: Application Gateway Backend Settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using AGIC, you should control these settings from ingress annotations and not directly change it on application gateway.

You can use:

```
appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/request-timeout: "900"
```

Reference: https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/annotations/#request-timeout